# How do I properly escape '=' in my string replacement script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, string

I have made a batch script that replaces strings in a specified text-based file. Within my file, the string `OutDir=bin` should be replaced as `OutDir=Build` but gets output as `bin=OutDir=Build=bin`. How do  I escape the `=` in `OutDir=bin` so that the string doesn't become garbled? I have tried `OutDir^=` but using the carrot doesn't work either.

Here is my current script:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set search=OutDir=bin
    set replace=OutDir=Build

    set textFile=%DOCUMENT%.txt

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
```

I have attempted to change the find and replace variables to compensate for the `=` in the string I'm replacing but none have worked:

```
set search= "OutDir=bin"
set replace= "OutDir=Build"

set search="OutDir=bin"
set replace="OutDir=Build"

set "search=OutDir=bin"
set "replace=OutDir=Build"

"set search=OutDir=bin"
"set replace=OutDir=Build"
```

Comment: I assume you've already Googled this some but read over this and all the answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556676/batch-file-how-to-replace-equal-signs-and-a-string-variable) but the answer by dbenham in particular and the link he provides on DosTips for some additional ideas, etc. This may be easier to tackle with Batch using a little PowerShell if that's something you are willing to try—you should be able to put some PowerShell right into the batch and let it do it via PowerShell but it could be transparent if you write it correctly so you just have a batch script you run.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with PowerShell to even _attempt_ it. This is being integrated with an existing batch script, so it must be batch.

Comment: Possibly, but there is *much* more that would need to be translated. Since I'm so inexperienced this would have to be done almost entirely by someone else. I'm also converting the script (once complete) into an `exe` binary with Bat To Exe Converter, adding code from another language will likely break it after the conversion.

Comment: I understand everything you are saying. In case you want to give it a simple try to see if it would potentially work and it gives you the desired output, look over the text here of a quick batch script you can run as batch just like you do any other batch script: https://justpaste.it/1f9xv. Please remember that PowerShell is Windows native and the language is really just text so if the exe conversion doesn't mess up text of a batch then it shouldn't do the same here. This should be simple enough for you to do a small test I suppose so in case you find it helpful, there you go.

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if you find anything helpful or needing adjusting or confirm it could work upon testing, etc. please let me know. I'll be happy to add an answer with much more detail if you think it could even be possible in your environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this as soon as I can. I'll get back to you with the results when my testing is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71165/discussion-between-mr-mendelli-and-it-snuggles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replacing the Equal Symbol `=` in a String with Batch using PowerShell

After testing and then research afterwards, I came upon [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556676/batch-file-how-to-replace-equal-signs-and-a-string-variable/9561827#9561827) which then also pointed to [this thread and posts on DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1485) and replacing the `=` with pure batch isn't easy.

When I run into issues with batch scripting where it takes a ton of complex batch logic or just cannot figure out how to get it to work easily, I usually try incorporating some **PowerShell** into the mix since it's **Windows** native and it can be much more robust than batch without complex logic.

> **The below batch script will essentially:**
>
> - Use [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) and [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) for the string to search
>     and replace
> - Then it will use [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html) to put the newly
>     replaced string back into the file accordingly

### Script

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set search=OutDir=bin
set replace=OutDir=Build
set textFile=%DOCUMENT%.txt

:PowerShell
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
ECHO (Get-Content "%~dp0%textFile%").replace("%search%", "%replace%") ^| Set-Content "%~dp0%textFile%">"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
EXIT
```

### Output Result

```
OutDir=Build
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using a batch function for string replacement

The following function can be used.  It doesn't need a GOTO :EOF at the end because it always exits of it's own accord.

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:l_replace
SET "TEMP=x%~1x"
:l_replaceloop
FOR /f "delims=%~2 tokens=1*" %%x IN ("!TEMP!") DO (
IF "%%y"=="" set "TEMP=!TEMP:~1,-1!"&exit/b
set "TEMP=%%x%~3%%y"
)
GOTO :l_replaceloop
```

To use it simply call the function and then add the three needed parameters:

The variable to send, the string to look for, and the string to replace it with.

```
CALL :l_replace "!VARIABLE!" "=" "#"
SET VARIABLE=!TEMP!
```

Answer (score 0):

## Another method of using powershell within batch to replace strings

I know this is an old post at this point but I thought I would suggest a much simpler way to accomplish string replacement in batch script using a powershell commmand.  It's not so bad!

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
SET "OLDSTRING=stuff=stuff"

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -Command "$oldstring ='%OLDSTRING%'; $newstring = $oldstring -replace '=', '#'; $newstring"') DO SET "NEWSTRING=%%A"

ECHO %NEWSTRING%
```

The above example uses a variable with something obnoxious '=' and replaces it with some arbitrary other string '#'.  To make it easier to follow I kept the variable names uppercase for batch variables, and lowercase for the powershell variables.

To make it work to change strings over a text file you can nest one FOR loop inside another

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('type textfile.txt') DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -Command "$oldstring ='%%B'; $newstring = $oldstring -replace '=', '#'; $newstring"') DO ECHO %%A>>newtextfile.txt
```

The above loops over the lines in a text file, does the replacment, and creates a new text file with the changes made.  You could then delete the old text file and rename the new file to the old file's name.  This is one way to do it, there are others of course.